# If $S_1=\sum_{n=1}^{\inf} a_n10^n$ is convergent, then is $S_2=\sum_{n=1}^{\inf} a_n(-9)^n$ convergent?

Tags: calculus, convergence-divergence

The problem is in the title. I'm not sure how to go about answering this question. My first thoughts were to say that the absolute value $S_2$ is less than the $S_1$, but this logic is incorrect because the convergence of $S_1$ does not imply its absolute convergence.

Comment: It suffices to notice that $|a_n|10^n\to 0.$

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc why is this true that the absolute value goes to 0?

Comment: When the series is convergent then its individual term tends to zero.

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc I understand this, how does this prove convergence of $S_2$ as while it proves that the nth term of $S_2$ goes to 0, this does not imply convergence.

Comment: $|a_n|9^n = ... |a_n|10^n$ Fill the space marked with three dots.

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc ... = (9/10)^n, but this does not answer the question that convergence does not imply absolute convergence?

Comment: Look at my first comment and apply the comparison test with constant times $(9/10)^n.$

Answer (score 0):

The following theorem should be an any calculus textbook:
$(*)$ If $\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n x^n$ converges, and $|y|<|x|$,
then $\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n y^n$ converges absolutely.

The proof hint is: comparison with a geometric series.

Note that $(*)$  is used to prove the existence of
"radius of convergence".  [So I would not recommend Sauron's approach to use the radius of convergence to prove $(*)$ .]